# Change root directory on npm publish

Tags: node.js, path, npm, package, node-modules

Is it possible to change the root directory of my Node.js npm package when I do a publish? What I have is following:

```
├── lib
├── package.json
├── .npmignore
├── src
│   ├── index.js
│   └── sub
│       └── mymodule.js
└── test
```

In `/src` is all of my ES2015 source code. I transpile that with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) into my `/lib` directory. The `main` in my `package.json` points to `lib/index.js`. After that I can make a `npm publish` (my `.npmignore` is set to `src` so only `lib` will be published). Now my package is deployed to npmjs.com and in another package I can import it with `import index from 'mypackage'`.

So far so good. But what if I want to import `sub/mymodule.js` directly? I have to write `import mymodule from 'mypackage/lib/sub/mymodule'`. What I really want is `import mymodule from 'mypackage/sub/mymodule'` without `/lib/` in my path.

How can I achieve this? The npm documentation mentioned [directories.lib](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#directorieslib) that I can set in `package.json` but it seems it will be completely ignored. I set it to `./lib` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

You can publish your `/lib` directory instead with `npm publish lib`.
Remember to copy your package.json file to the lib directory before publish.

A suggestion is to use npm scripts:

`"scripts": {
  "build": "babel src --out-dir lib",
  "prepublish": "npm run build && cp ./package.json lib"
}`

Comment: Yes, thank you, but that's a very ugly and error-prone workaround for that because you have to cd into `/lib` and do a `npm publish` from that directory. Imagine you forgot that step und do a `npm publish` accidentally from the root directory of your project. You end up in a library that does not work anymore.

Comment: I came across this comment today and figured out that you can set `private: true` in `package.json`, which prevents all publish attempts. then in your `/lib` directory, make sure to grep out `private: true` while copying `package.json`, this limits you to publish only in your prepared directory.

Answer (score 3):

I too have been experiencing exactly the same pain. After a lot of playing around I ended up with an answer based on the one in this post:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "lint": "eslint src/**",
  "build": "rm -rf ./lib/* && babel src -d lib -s && cp ./package.json lib",
  "prepublish": "[[ \"$PWD\" =~ YOUR_DIR_HERE/lib ]]",
  "pub": "pushd ./ && npm run build && cd lib && npm publish && popd"
}
```

This means that an "npm publish" will fail when not in the lib dir which prevents mistaken deployments. I am not keen on having to use a custom "npm run pub" but this is the best solution I have been able to come up with for now.

Comment: Ugh - I was hoping to find a better answer than this. I am doing the same thing. I don't really mind "npm publish" failing if I'm doing this by hand from a cli, but the problem is, now I have an special case for all our build tools that publish automatically. I can no longer just assume that "npm publish" is how you publish a package.